# "print txt.read" in Python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working through Learn Python the Hard Way, exercise 15. The script I am trying to run is:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print("Here's your file %r:" %(filename)
print txt.read()

print("Type the filename again:")
file_again = raw_input(> ")

text_again = open(file_again)

print txt_again.read()
```

When I run the script I get the error: 'Invalid Syntax', and it points to the "print txt.read" portion of the code (line 5).

As stated, I am using python 3, and I know this book is written for Python 2. So my question is: what is the Python 3 equivalent of "print txt.read"?

Many thanks

Comment: Please please please don't use LPTHW. See [here](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints) for some reasons. Other, better tutorials can be found [here](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F).

Comment: I've started, so I'll finish.

Comment: Your choice, but a lot of us here strongly recommend against it, especially if you're only at Ex 15. Do what you want, though.

Comment: Allow me to elaborate, I realise my first response may have been rather blunt.

Comment: I am finding this book very good. It is forcing me to really use my brain to solve the problems...and because I on python 3 and the book is on python 2, it is forcing me to learn both versions at once. Yes the tone of the book is very blunt. But I'm a no nonsense kind of guy and can deal with....in my humble opinion people are being too sensitive, they should just get on with it. But thats just my personal opinion. Like you said, each to their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to `print` needing to be a function (i.e. `print()`), your example is missing a starting quote on the line for raw_input.  It should be:

```
file_again = raw_input("> ")
```

And, you're missing a closing parentheses on one of the `print` lines.

Comment: `raw_input` is no longer a function in Python 3.

Comment: @ Brian - Thank you sir! The problem was not with "print txt.read", it was with "print("Here's your file %r:" %(filename)".......as you said, I missed off a closing parenthesis. Once I resolved that it worked.

Comment: Also my other mistake was: "text_again = open(file_again)" and "print txt_again.read()".......using 'text' and 'txt'

Comment: @user5185132 In python 3, `raw_input` gives you `NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined`. Python 3 dumped the old python 2 `input` and renamed `raw_input` to `input`.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(txt.read())
```

[print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function call in python 3

Comment: Unfprtunately that is not working for me either...I get the following message:

Comment: File "ex15.py", line 8

    print(txt.read())

        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user5185132 that because you are missing a `)` in the line above this line

Comment: @user5185132 `print("Here's your file %r:" %(filename))` also change raw_input to input

Comment: yes, Brian also spotted the same mistake....but why did the error message point to the line below?.....completely wrong-footed me....

Comment: @SnakeInTheGrass dats because python thinks its a multiline statement so expect a `)` in the next line.When it doesnt find it der,it fails

Comment: @SnakeInTheGrass The SyntaxError is raised at the point python gets confused. Open parens can cross new line boundaries so it wasn't until later that python realized there was a problem.

Comment: @vks & tdelaney - Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score -2):

try to encapsulate it, what I did is:

```
print(txt.read())
```

I'm using python 3.

Comment: this adds nothing to the existing answers, whatsoever. Worse even, what you describe as encapsulation, is not [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))